# How to manage many modules in git repository

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have a project with several modules, some depends on others, for example:

- `X`
- `A, which depends on X`
- `B, which depends on X`

Developing `A` or `B` cause many changes in X.

I have development branch on git where I am developming A and B.

How can I manage pushing A or B to some sort of stable branch?

I mean, I have situation like:

[Actual Stable Branch version, commit after this are in develompent branch]

- Commit1: changes A and X
- Commit2: changes B and X
- Commit3: changes A and X

After commit 3 I want push A to stable.
So I need Commit1:A,X, Commit2:X, Commit3:A,X

Is there any way to do this?
I don't want additional repositories inside this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need an additional repo, ie a "parent repo" which will memorize the exact commits of `A`, `B`, and `X`.
This is what **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** are for: `A`, `B` and `X` would be declared submodules of a parent repo.

you would push your modifications as usual (to the branch of your choice), but *in addition* you would also commit and push the parent repo, in order to record the commits of each submodules.
See "[True nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)" for more on that way of working.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for reply, I'll read it, maybe I was using sumbmodules wrong way